# How to count the number of uppercase characters in a NSString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, nsstring, range

I'm trying to find out the best way to count the number of uppercase characters that are in a NSString. I know how to find out if a certain character is uppercase by using this code:

```
NSString *s = @"This is a string";
BOOL isUppercase = [[NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[s characterAtIndex:0]];
```

What would be the best way to count the number of uppercase letters in a NSString? Thanks.

Comment: A very short although not the most performant way:`[[s componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet]] count] - 1;`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
NSString *s = @"This is a string";  
int count=0;  
for (i = 0; i < [s length]; i++) {
    BOOL isUppercase = [[NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[s characterAtIndex:i]];
    if (isUppercase == YES)
       count++;
}
```

`count` is the number of uppercase occurences.

Comment: Your code gives me a weird number at first 79050146 then it begins to work... really weird. Any ideas why this is giving me this long number?

Comment: If you are printing out `count` in the loop before it is initialized it will give a strange value. change `int count;` to `int count = 0;` to prevent garbage values.

Answer (score 2):

Walk through the indices in the string one by one and add `1` to a counter whenever you find an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 1):

One line solution

```
 NSUInteger count = [[[@"A string HERE!!" componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""] length]; // count = 5
```