# How to code for a password needing a number and capital letter in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Looking for coding or ideas to help me get a good start on ways for a program to check, after tapping a button, the a UITextField for at least one capital letter, at least one number and a length >= 6. Looking towards if statements so the else code could send out an alert telling its missing something.

am pretty much new to coding and was directed by my teacher to ask on here, thank you

Comment: We're not here to write your code for you.  And shame on your instructor for having you doing Objective-C coding if you do not already know the fundamentals of C.

Comment: You can try Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend checking each one individually and then only logging on (progressing) if they all come back ok

**Checking the length**

```
// Check if the text is a certain length
if (textField.text.length >= 6) {  
}
```

**Checking that is contains a number**

```
if ([textField.text rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]].location != NSNotFound) {
}
```

**Checking that it contains an uppercase character**

```
NSString * string = textField.text;  
int count = 0;  
for (i = 0; i < [s length]; i++) {
    BOOL isUppercase = [[NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[s characterAtIndex:i]];
    if (isUppercase == YES)
       count++;
}
```

This code is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141545/how-to-count-the-number-of-uppercase-characters-in-a-nsstring) and loops through the string checking if there are upper case characters contained in it. You can then check the value of count to see if there is at least one it in. If you want a stronger password you can increase this check too.

In future though this is all quite basic stuff which just requires time to find out instead of knowledge of C. I didn't know how to do any of this before having a look to write this answer.

Hopefully this helps your understanding and, going forward, try spending 30 minutes searching with google before posting a duplicate question

Some more good questions on this can be seen below.

This answer here: [is almost the same as the one you have asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984912/check-if-nsstring-contains-any-numbers-and-is-at-least-7-characters-long)
This answer also covers special characters: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730435/how-to-check-whether-the-nsstring-object-contains-special-characters-integers-o)

Answer (score 0):

As Hot Licks says, this is not a "write my code for me" site. This is a site to get help with specific problems.

Take a look at the NSString class reference in Xcode. You should read the whole thing. It lists lots and lots of very useful methods. You won't understand it all at first, but note methods that sound like the would be useful.

Big hint: You'll also want to take a look at the NSCharacterSet class, and NSString methods that use NSCharacterSet to search in a string for characters that belong to specific set of characters.

Note that you could probably also use regular expressions. Cocoa includes the NSRegularExpression class, which lets you apply regular expressions to strings.

Comment: thanks you for taking your time, I dont expect anyone to write the code for me. I was mainly in hope to see some kind of sample code (maybe something that might even have just one of the requirements) and  from there i can see what methods to call. if that was to much to ask for sorry, hoped i didnt seem i was just wanting the code am really just learning on my own.